# How can I use conditional rendering when I use styled components and map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am going to do conditional rendering using styled components and map function. I want to change the font size at `styled component Wrap1_3` according to the id value of the array. How can I do that? I want to know how to give different values depending on the value of the array.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';


***code***
I made array and map function in this file. And also used css by styled components

function ProfileChange() {

  const array = [
    {
      id : '1',
      text : '프로필 편집'
    },
    {
      id : '2',
      text : '비밀번호 변경'
    },
    {
      id : '3',
      text : '앱 및 웹사이트'
    },
  ]



  return (
    <>
      <ProfileWrap>
        <div className='Wrap1'>
          <ul className='Wrap1_1'>
            {
              array.map((a,i)=>{
                return (
                  <li className='Wrap1_2'>
                    <div className='Wrap1_3'>
                      {a.text}
                    </div>
                  </li>
                )
              })
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ProfileWrap>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProfileChange;

const ProfileWrap = styled.div`
  width: calc(100% - 244px);
  margin-left: auto;


  .Wrap1 {
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    background-color: rgb(255,2552,255);
    border: 1px solid rgb(219,219,219);
  }

  .Wrap1_1 {
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(219,219,219);
    display: flex;
  }

  .Wrap1_2 {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .Wrap1_3 {
    padding: 16px 16px 16px calc(32px - 2px);
    color: rgb(38,38,38);
    font-weight: 600;
    /* I want to change font size here */
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

Comment: `<div className={id === 1 ? 'Wrap1_3' : 'Wrap1_2'}>`

Comment: You can make a different styled component for Wrap1_3 then you can use props to change font-size dynamically.